# Ставится ли запятая перед"при виде"?

Tags: пунктуация

При виде этой кошки у нее чувство страха.

Comment: Нет. Предложение не может начинаться с запятой, даже если в нём пропущено сказуемое. Вы хотели спросить о запятой **после** "при виде"? Вообще, лучше сомнительное место указывать в скобках, например: "При виде(,) этой кошки у неё возникало чувство страха". Тогда Вас лучше поймут.

Comment: Джамиля, Вы же видели предыдущий комментарий, но почему-то не исправили свой вопрос. И еще один момент: система благодарности включает не только принятие ответа галочкой, но и дополнительное поощрение в виде стрелочки (треугольника) вверх. Это касается всех Ваших вопросов, где стрелочкой можно отметить **все** полезные ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предложение  при пропуске сказуемого выглядит стилистически некорректным.
Варианты  редактирования (выбор зависит от контекста – насколько подробно  раскрывается тема «кошки»):

(1) ***При виде этой кошки** // у нее возникает чувство страха*.

(2) *У нее при виде этой кошки  // возникает чувство страха*.

Обособление **обстоятельственного оборота**  в начале предложения не требуется, так как оборот  входит в состав предложения (обычное деление простого предложения на две части, пауза произносительная, не грамматическая).